# Indentation instead of brackets for Antlr4

Tags: java, python, grammar, indentation, antlr4

I'm currently attending the course "Compilers Construction" and I'm developing a simplified Java grammar in Antlr 4. The part involving Java grammar works just fine, except that it is slightly different from the original Java.

I'm told I should no use brackets and instead use indentation. I have tried a few examples from the internet, only examples for Antlr 3 which won't work in Antlr 4.

Can anyone help me with this indentation issue, or provide me the Python grammar for Antlr 4?

Answer (score 2):

What about official GitHub [ANTLR4 grammar repository](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4)? You can find many common language grammars. There is even a [python3 directory](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/python3) containing `Python3.g4`.

This should help you out.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a small library that helps with exactly this use case: [antlr-denter](https://github.com/yshavit/antlr-denter).

In short, you define INDENT and DEDENT tokens in your grammar, do a bit of boilerplate stuff to hook the antlr-denter into antlr's generated lexer, and away you go. For instance, code that looks like this:

```
hello:
    world
<eof>
```

Might generate the token stream `WORD COLON INDENT WORD DEDENT`.